# can not read correctly from STDIN

Tags: python, rsyslog

I have a weird problem to read from STDIN in a python script.

Here is my use case. I have rsyslog configured with an output module so rsyslog can pipe log messages to my Python script.

My Python script is really trivial :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

fd = open('/tmp/testrsyslogomoutput.txt', 'a')
fd.write("Receiving log message : \n%s\n" % ('-'.join(sys.stdin.readlines())))
fd.close()
```

If I run `echo "foo" | mypythonscript.py` I can get "foo" in the target file `/tmp/testrsyslogomoutput.txt`. However when I run it within rsyslog, messages seems to be sent only when I stop/restart rsyslog (I believe some buffer is flushed at some point).

I first thought it was a problem with Rsyslog. So I replaced my python program with a shell one, without changing anything to the rsyslog configuration. The shell script works perfectly with rsyslog and as you can see in the code below, the script is really trivial:

```
#! /bin/sh
cat /dev/stdin >> /tmp/testrsyslogomoutput.txt
```

Since my shell script works but my Python one does not, I believe I made a mistake somewhere in my Python code but I can not find where. If you could point me to my mistake(s) that would be great.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd also suspect the reason is that rsyslog does not terminate. `readlines()` should not return until it reaches a real EOF. But why would the shell script act differently? Perhaps the use of /dev/stdin is the reason. Try this version and see if it still runs without hanging:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat >> /tmp/testrsyslogomoutput.txt
```

If this makes a difference, you'll also have a fix: open and read /dev/stdin from python, instead of sys.stdin.

Edit: So `cat` somehow reads whatever is waiting at stdin and returns, but python blocks and waits until stdin is exhausted. Strange. You can also try replacing `readlines()` with a single `read()` followed by `split("\n")`, but at this point I doubt that will help.

So, forget the diagnosis and let's try a work-around: Force stdin to do non-blocking i/o. The following is supposed to do that:

```
import fcntl, os

# Add O_NONBLOCK to the stdin descriptor flags 
flags = fcntl.fcntl(0, fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(0, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)

message = sys.stdin.read().split("\n")  # Read what's waiting, in one go
fd = open('/tmp/testrsyslogomoutput.txt', 'a')
fd.write("Receiving log message : \n%s\n" % ('-'.join(message)))
fd.close()
```

You probably want to use that in combination with `python -u`. Hope it works!

Comment: I tried what you proposed it does not make any difference. It still works perfectly with this trivial shell script. I also tried to read from /dev/stdin in my python script (without readlines()) and it still hangs.

Comment: Oh well. Next idea: take python's i/o buffering out of the equation by invoking python with the -u flag.

Comment: Thanks for your support Alexis, I also tried with python -u and it did not change anything.

Comment: It seems @abalus got kind of the same problem with Apache : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056306/python-wait-until-data-is-in-sys-stdin

Comment: I think @abalus had the opposite problem: In his set-up the reads return immediately without blocking, but your program blocks when cat somehow returns without blocking.

Comment: I owe you a pint. I would have never thought about adding 0_NONBLOCK to sys.stdin. It works, thanks a lot !

Comment: :-) Glad it worked! I'm still wondering why cat didn't block, though... tk

Answer (score 3):

`readlines` will not return until it has finished reading the file. Since the pipe feeding stdin never finishes, `readlines` never finishes either. Stopping rsyslog closes the pipe and lets it finish.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `readline()` instead, it will return on `\n`, though this will only write one line then quit.

If you want to keep writing lines as long they are there, you can use a simple `for`:

```
for line in fd:
  fd.write("Receiving log message : \n%s\n" % (line)
fd.close()
```

Comment: I tried this. The problem remains the same. I tried to loop over sys.stdin and /dev/stdin and the input is only written when \n is sent. Using an alternative to readline as suggested above did not work either.