# Python scripts piped in bash - consumer gets no data when producer is slow?

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, pipe, stdin

I've got two Python scripts. One makes a database query, parses the output, and writes a formatted form line-by-line (to a file or to `stdout` as determined by command-line arguments, processed/opened by `argparse`).

The second, after about a minute of parsing static files, reads line-by-line (from a file or `stdin`, uses `argparse`, etc.), processes that, and writes its own output (file or `stdout`, determined by `argparse`).

Both work fine when unpiped (`$ ./1.py argsfile midfile; ./2.py argsfile midfile outfile`).

On smaller queries from the first script, piping the two together also works fine, and is actually a good bit faster (`$ ./1.py - | ./2.py - outfile`).

However, when the database query of the first script is large, doing the two separately still works but piping them does not - my best guess is that the second script is finishing its preprocessing, checking `stdin`, seeing it empty because the first script hasn't written to it yet, and proceeding on with nothing. Parse nothing, return nothing, write nothing to file.

[The previous question/answer I've found on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7056462/6051861) seems to indicate that this shouldn't be possible, that `for line in infile` where the `infile` is standard input should block until closed. I've also tried

```
while True:
    line = infile.readline()
    if line == '':
        break
    else:
        pass # actual processing
```

but that doesn't work either. I can't drop the conditional and the break entirely because then it would block forever, and this is not meant for reading an endless stream, just some piped input that's taking a while to start arriving.

Keeping it in separate scripts is a requirement due to business constraints (minimize the number of difficulties in changing away from the systems involved in either of the two steps, if the time ever comes).

Comment: Output to a pipe is buffered; `1.py` isn't writing enough to fill up the buffer, so `2.py` has to wait until either `1.py` completes and closes its end of the pipe or it writes enough to the buffer for the OS to flush it to `2.py`.

Comment: Ignoring SIGPIPE strikes me as a Bad Thing here -- if you're having a FD close early, you should probably figure out *why* that's happening. If you could [build a reproducer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that would be helpful -- right now, this is a "I have this thing that shouldn't ever happen" post, but without sufficient code or details on how to make that thing *happen*; it's hard to debug without something concrete.

Comment: @chepner Will try manual flushing or forcing no buffer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The only code that actually touches the file/pipe boils down to `for element in parsed: outfile.write(json.dumps(element) + '\n')` to write, and either `for line in infile` or the `readlines` thing from the question to read. Can't test if that's sufficient to replicate until tomorrow. Meanwhile, attaching debuggers to a piped script seems to involve waiting for all input and redirecting it so the debugger can see the keyboard... Which is effectively what I did by writing to an intermediate file, which didn't have the problem.

Comment: Eh? Attaching a debugger requires no such thing. Run `yourscript` in your pipeline as you normally would (maybe with some delays inserted to give you a chance to attach), and use the gdb `attach` command to attach to it from a completely different console window.

Comment: ...now, granted, for a Python process it's a little more interesting, but only a little -- there are plenty of off-the-shelf recipes to allow a UNIX socket to be used to connect to your debugger. See (as my very first Google result) https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpcpdb, or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/manhole (which actually looks like the more mature of the two), or the WingIDE debugger, or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/remote-pdb -- this is a wheel that's reinvented on a darned near continual basis.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Removed the mention of the `signal` ignoring - I removed that line from the code and it changed nothing.

Comment: Good to hear. Where are you on having `1.py` and `2.py` implementations you can include in the question that repro the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125008/discussion-between-david-heyman-and-charles-duffy).